# How could this user have reviewed this queue?

Tags: bug, reviews

While looking at who was rewarded the Custodian Badge, I noticed that the user [this user](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/47903/heyyy) was [rewarded the custodian badge for completing a review task](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/badges/81/custodian?userid=47903) in the queue [suggested edits](https://writing.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/stats). Their only Stack account is Writing SE and in Writing the user has less than 200 reputation points. You need 1k amount of reputation points to review the suggested edits queue.

**How did the user review in the suggested edits queue if they didn't have enough rep points to do so?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always approve or reject suggested edits to your own posts regardless of reputation. You can see here the edit they approved on their own question:

https://writing.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/23851

Comment: Yes you get the badge for it, I've seen the same things on a few sites.